# Freemarker variable not re-assigning value

Tags: freemarker

I'm trying to generate a JSON template. To ensure that I don't have any trailing commas I'm doing the following:

```
<@s.Results>
    <#assign delimiter = "">
    ${delimiter}{
        "title": "${s.result.title}"
    }
    <#assign delimiter = ",">
</@s.Results>
```

But the value is not being re-assigned - it's just the original value (empty string). Am I doing something wrong? According to the docs it should re-assing - http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_misc_var.html

Comment: When's `delimiter` printed for the 2nd time? Does `s.Result` execute its nested content for multiple times maybe?

Comment: OMG. That is such a simple mistake I've made. I've just started using this template syntax, that's my excuse. Thanks for pointing out the obvious :)

Comment: I think this is resolved.